# Spring no WEB-INF and web.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-bean

I've created my first spring project today. It works but I don't understand everything(I think this is normal after only a day).

I am doing dependency injection by add @Component or @Service to the class that can be injected. This works fine, but on google I see people using an xml file with `<beans>` tags. I would like to use this to, but I can't get the file to get read by springs.

In this project(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF) I see that the beans xml(root-context and servlet-context file in that project) are registered in the `web.xml`.
But I don't have a `web.xml`! I also don't have the `WEB-INF` directory.

Did I do something wrong in the Spring Initializr setup?
And how can I get those?

Comment: Well the whole directory structure around `WEB-INF`, including `web.xml`, isn't Spring specific, but rather JEE. You can manually create a `web.xml`, or take a sample and modify it to your satisfaction.

Comment: No, nothing is wrong. Using XML to declare your beans is the old way of dealing with Spring. Spring now promotes Java and annotation-based configuration, which is simpler, less verbose, safer, and easier to deal with. Why do you want to have XML?

Comment: @jingx Thanks! When I create them it just works? Or do I have to do something more.

Comment: @JBNizet I thought it would be nice to have all the thinks that can be injected at one place. But you are probably right ;)